# How do I create an index in PostgreSQL based on lowercase only?

Tags: string, postgresql, indexing

How would I set up an index based on lower case only?

Even though the actual field contains both upper and lower case letters.

Also, can I run a query and have only the lower case index value returned?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can create the index and transform the field to upper- or lower-case. Then when you do your queries, you can do the same transform and it'll do the right thing.

So:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lower_case_username ON users ((lower(username)));
```

Then query for the same thing:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE lower(username) = 'bob';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's my SQL statement:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "lcase_idx" ON "public"."members"
  USING btree ((lower(Memb_Name)));

ERROR:  column "memb_name" does not exist. 

It seems that rather than using a lowercase of Memb_Name to build the index, the lower function is just making the name of the field referenced lower case. I tried it with and without quotes around Memb_Name.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL are you using? I just did that on one of my tables (on 8.3) and it worked fine.  What does "\d public.members" show for that column?

Comment: I don't know what "\d public.members" is. I'm using 8.4-- I got it to work on another test table.

Comment: Oh, yes; PostgreSQL is case-sensitive pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Oh and "\d table_name" is a way to get the server to dump out the table info.

Comment: Also, make sure that you set your bind var to lowercase ;-)

Comment: Forgive me but what is the point of creating a lower case index if you have to lower() the column in your query anyway?  using lower prevents postgres from using an index.

Comment: @glyph No, Postgresql is smart enough to recognize that a function application matches the definition of an index. [Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-expressional.html)

Comment: Why use the `((` and `))`? Can it work with `ON users (lower(username));`?

Comment: great answer. Works great.

Comment: The comment is way old but @111 asks a good question imo, why is `lower` needed on the column name in the query?

Comment: @foba because that makes the index be built from the lower-case version of the username, which is the whole point.

Answer (score 13):

According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createindex.html) you can do this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lower_title_idx ON films ((lower(title)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's my SQL statement:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "lcase_idx" ON "public"."members"
  USING btree ((lower(Memb_Name)));

ERROR:  column "memb_name" does not exist. 

It seems that rather than using a lowercase of Memb_Name to build the index, the lower function is just making the name of the field referenced lower case. I tried it with and without quotes around Memb_Name.

Comment: PS: I seems to work fine... only IF the field name is all lower case.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this for wildcard searches:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS foo_table_bar_field ON foo_table(lower(username))
```

Query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM foo_table WHERE lower(username) like 'bob%'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index_name ON my_table (LOWER(my_field));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's my SQL statement:

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "lcase_idx" ON "public"."members"
  USING btree ((lower(Memb_Name)));

ERROR:  column "memb_name" does not exist. 

It seems that rather than using a lowercase of Memb_Name to build the index, the lower function is just making the name of the field referenced lower case. I tried it with and without quotes around Memb_Name.

Comment: PS: I seems to work fine... only IF the field name is all lower case.

Comment: This is a decade later, but AFAIK PostgreSQL assumes lowercase symbol names unless you explicitly quote them. In your case, you needed to use `lower("Memb_Name")`