# How to make postgresql search method case-insensitive?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I just switched from sqlite3 to postgresql-9.4. Before, when I search with my method "typeahead", I would get results that were not case-sensitive. But now that I switched, the method is suddenly case-sensitive. How can I make the method case-insensitive with postgresql?

```
def typeahead
  q = params[:query]
  render json: Subject.where('name like ? OR second_name like ? OR keywords like ?', "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%")
end
```

Comment: Typically, if you have a field of values you're searching, you should fold the contents to either lower or uppercase before inserting, then convert your search text to lower, or upper, case when you search. That allows your code to work on any DBM without relying on DBM-specific functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use ILIKE instead of LIKE

```
 Subject.where('name ilike ? OR second_name ilike ? OR keywords ilike ?', "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%")
```

or to simplify a little

```
 Subject.where('name ilike :name OR second_name ilike :name OR keywords ilike :name', name: "%#{q}%")
```

Comment: This works fine, but it's worth noting that it is PostgreSQL specific.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use "ilike" keyword instead "like".

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to do this:

```
Subject.where('LOWER(name) like ?, "%#{q.downcase}%")
```

Note that you might need to create a lowercase index if you suffer performance issues. See: [How do I create an index in PostgreSQL based on lowercase only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980050/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-postgresql-based-on-lowercase-only)

Comment: I see, great solution! Could I also do `q = params[:query].downcase` to save some computing power?

Comment: JoeMorano yes you can but you shouldn't care much about this type of optimizations as its effect will be negligible, instead you should on focus on performance issues like IO and database issues and network issues like the one Drenmi addressed in his answer.