# How to use Lowercase function in Sequelize Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to use the lowercase function to do string searching in Sequelize.
I manage to do it using the ilike. 
My question is how to use the lowercase function in this scenario?

The `findAll` using ilike is as following:

```
Db.models.Person.findAll(where: {firstName: {$ilike: `somename`}});
```

How do I change it to `lower(firstname) = lower('somename');`

Comment: dont know if that apply to you, but in my case i try using unaccent function in C# linq and couldnt make it work, at the end just create a new column `u_column` and use postgres function to fill it. Wasnt preatty but work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

PostgreSQL generally uses case-sensitive collations. This means data that appears in each column is compared literally against your query.

You have several options:

---

**1. Follow Ben's answer, and wrap your wrap columns and database in a `sequelize.fn('lower')` call.**

Pros: No database changes.

Cons: You need to remember to use it for every query. Foregoes indexes (unless you've already created a [functional index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980083/216012)) and scans tables sequentially, resulting in slower look-ups with large tables. Quite verbose code.

---

**2. Use ILIKE, to case-insensitively match a pattern**

To find the name exactly:

`Db.models.Person.findAll(where: {firstName: {$iLike: 'name'}});`

To find a fragment, which may be contained within arbitrary characters:

`Db.models.Person.findAll(where: {firstName: {$iLike: '%name%'}});`

Pros: Easy to remember. No Sequelize function wrappers - it's a built-in operator, so syntax is neater. No special indexes or database changes required.

Cons: Slow, unless you start messing with extensions like [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html)

---

**3. Define your text columns with the [citext](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/citext.html) type, which implicitly compares lowercase**

Defining your column types as 'citext' (instead of `text` or `character varying`) has the same practical effect of turning this:

`select * from people where name = 'DAVID'`

to this...

`select * from people where LOWER(name) = LOWER('DAVID')`

The PostgreSQL documentation shows this as an example of how to create your table  with the citext type:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    nick CITEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    pass TEXT   NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'larry',  md5(random()::text) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Tom',    md5(random()::text) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Damian', md5(random()::text) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'NEAL',   md5(random()::text) );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 'Bjørn',  md5(random()::text) );

SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick = 'Larry';
```

TL;DR basically swap out your "text" columns for "citext".

The citext module comes bundled with PostgreSQL 8.4, so there's no need to install any extensions. But you do need to enable it on each database you use it with the following SQL:

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;`

And then in your Sequelize definitions, define a `type` attribute:

```
// Assuming `Conn` is a new Sequelize instance
const Person = Conn.define('person', {
  firstName: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: 'citext' // <-- this is the only change
  }
});
```

Then your searches against that column will *always* be case-insensitive with regular `where =` queries

Pros: No need to wrap your queries in ugly `sequelize.fn` calls. No need to remember to explicitly lowercase. Locale aware, so works across all character sets.

Cons: You need to remember to use it in your Sequelize definitions when first defining your table. Always activated - you need to know that you'll want to do case insensitive searching when defining your tables.

Comment: I did the 3rd solution with the following migration. Might be useful for others: module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;');
    queryInterface.sequelize.query('CREATE TABLE mytable(email CITEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL);');
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.dropTable('mytable');
  }
};

Comment: Re #2: Additional code may be necessary to escape special characters in `name` if it's coming from a user.

Comment: I wonder how someone would design for case-insensitive searches generally, but still opt into case-sensitive matching sometimes. Would we need to do a second pass in application code to apply the case-sensitivity, or is there a SQL operator that means "this time, honor case, even though this field is citext"?

Comment: Another con for CITEXT imho is that it cannot be combined with a maxlength for the field! Also, it's quite a hassle to set it up correctly when using a dockerized psql database, but that may be an individual thing.

Answer (score 18):

You can use native functions in the where clause:

```
Db.models.Person.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('firstname')), 
    sequelize.fn('lower', 'somename')
  )
});
```

which would translate to

```
select * from person where lower(firstname) = lower('somename');
```

Comment: using this way, when I need to search mutiple arguments how should I do it.
For example: lastName and Phone Number. where lastName is similar tyep of field like firstName, phoneNumber is a field where it stores numbers.

Comment: you would just add them as normal to your `where: {}` object.

`where: {
   sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('firstname')), sequelize.fn('lower', 'somename')),
   phoneNumber: 8435551212
}`

Comment: @Ben: This does not work for me, I suggest: `where: {phoneNumber: '8435551212', $col: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('lower', sequelize.col('firstname')), sequelize.fn('lower', 'somename'))}`