# PostgreSQL: Create lowercase index using C# Entity Framework migrations

Tags: c#, postgresql, indexing, entity-framework-migrations

I'm checking this article [PostgreSQL lowercase index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980050/how-do-i-create-an-index-in-postgresql-based-on-lowercase-only) and wonder what is the cleanest way to implement the lowercase constraint from C# using EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations:

Can the lowercase constraint somehow be implemented via C#?

In C# in the `OnModelCreating` method, I tried something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<users>()
    .HasIndex(b => b.username.ToLower())
```

but this throws

```
System.ArgumentException: The expression 'user => user.username.ToLower()' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'.
```

Or is the only way to implement this via custom migrations operations like

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lower_case_username ON users ((lower(username)));");
```

Comment: How exactly it _"but it does not work."_? Does not compile, throws exception at runtime or does not create index?

Comment: @GuruStron throws an Argument Exception